# How do you rename apps in Django1.11 LTS?

Tags: python, django, django-apps

How do you rename apps in Django 1.11 LTS? There are suggestions in renaming apps in Django but they are for version <1.11 and are complicated. Anybody knows?

Comment: if you have a apps.py then its just an easy task

Comment: how do you actually do it?